# Accessing Mine data immediately after install

Tags: salt-stack

I am deploying a cluster via SaltStack (on Azure) I've installed the client, which initiates a reactor, runs an orchestration to push a Mine config, do an update, restart salt-minion.  (I upgraded that to restarting the box)

After all of that, I can't access the mine data until I restart the minion

/srv/reactor/startup_orchestration.sls

```
startup_orchestrate:
  runner.state.orchestrate:
    - mods: orchestration.startup
```

orchestration.startup

```
orchestration.mine:
  salt.state:
    - tgt: '*'
    - sls:
      - orchestration.mine

saltutil.sync_all:
  salt.function:
    - tgt: '*'
    - reload_modules: True

mine.update:
  salt.function:
    - tgt: '*'

highstate_run:
  salt.state:
    - tgt: '*'
    - highstate: True
```

orchestration.mine

```
  {% if salt['grains.get']('MineDeploy') != 'complete' %}

/etc/salt/minion.d/globalmine.conf:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt:///orchestration/files/globalmine.conf


MineDeploy:
  grains.present:
    - value: complete
    - require: 
      - service: rabbit_running

sleep 5 && /sbin/reboot:
  cmd.run


{%- endif %}
```

How can I push a mine update, via a reactor and then get the data shortly afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

I deploy my `mine_functions` from pillar so that I can update the functions on the fly
then you just have to do `salt <target> saltutil.refresh_pillar` and `salt <target> mine.update` to get your mine info on a new host.

Example:

`/srv/pillar/my_mines.sls`

```
mine_functions:
  aws_cidr:
    mine_function: grains.get
    delimiter: '|'
    key: ec2|network|interfaces|macs|{{ mac_addr }}|subnet_ipv4_cidr_block
  zk_pub_ips:
    - mine_function: grains.get
    - ec2:public_ip
```

You would then make sure your pillar's `top.sls` targets the appropriate minions, then do the `saltutil.refresh_pillar`/`mine.update` to get your mine functions updated & mines supplied with data. After taking in the above pillar, I now have mine functions called `aws_cidr` and `zk_pub_ips` I can pull data from.

One caveat to this method is that `mine_interval` has to be defined in the minion config, so that parameter wouldn't be doable via pillar. Though if you're ok with the default 60-minute interval, this is a non-issue.